# How to use assign inside a function when NOT assigning to the .GlobalEnv?

Tags: r, private, environment

Put it differently: How can I get the name of a function's environment (not its enclosing environment).

I am trying to assign the result of a function to a certain name inside a function. The name should not occur in the GlobalEnv. Still I do care about the name, because I process `deparse(substitute(x))` and therefore need to make sense of the name.

At the moment I just create an environment inside the function, which I feel is kind of a work around:

```
createList <- function(...,nm="nameString"){
myList <- list(...)
e1 <- new.env()
assign(nm,myList,envir=e1)
# obviously this does not make much sense
# just want to show that the envir thing works
e1[[nm]]
}
```

Is there any way to do this easier? Not the result, but assigning variable to a certain name
inside a function. `environment(createList)` just gives my back `.GlobalEnv`, the environment in which the function itself resides, but I want to know how the environment is called that variables inside the function live in. .Private?

Comment: `"Is there any way to do this easier?"` -- What is the ultimate goal?

Comment: Seconding @RicardoSaporta, and I suspect some others will jump in as well.

Comment: The ultimate goal was actually how find the hash that names the private environment of a function. Didn't know environment() without arguments does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `environment()` what you want?

```
createList <- function(...,nm="nameString"){
  myList <- list(...)
  assign(nm,myList,envir=environment())
  get(nm)
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise in my question. It was just difficult to ask what wanted to know without knowing what I know now. Anyway, just were pretty good at guessing! I will edit the question to help future googlers.